# What of the following two sentences sounds more native?

Tags: sentence-choice

What of the following two sentences sounds more native?

> 1) If you wonder why I hold a balloon, so I got this balloon in order to
>   hit Mike on his head with it
>
> 2) If you wonder why I hold a balloon, so I got this balloon in order to
>   hit with it on Mike's head.

Comment: None. "Balloon" is a singular count noun, needs an article before it. "So" seems unnatural. Concerning the ending part, the first sentence looks better.

Comment: Thank you. I put articles. What would you prefer to put in place of "so"?

Comment: I forgot to tell that this sentence describes a picture

Comment: Omit "so" entirely and replace it with nothing. The first one is better than the second. Most native: "I got this balloon to hit Mike on the head with it". Or, "I'm going to hit Mike on the head with this balloon next time I see him."

Comment: Regarding your question title, "which of" rather than "what of" sounds more natural to me.

Comment: @CopperKettle you mean *countable noun*?

Answer (score 9):

Neither sentence sounds native, both are too wordy.

A native AmE speaker would say

> If you're **wondering** why I have this balloon, **it's** to hit Mike on the head.

in response to a **quizzical look** at the balloon and the person holding it.

Comment: I like it. My alternate wording would be: _If you're wondering why I have this balloon, I'm going to hit Mike on the head with it._

Comment: Or potentially: _If you're wondering why I have this balloon, it's for hitting Mike on the head_.  Though by cutting out the "I got it" you do change the meaning of the sentence slightly, IMO, even if it does sound more natural.

Comment: I **got**, is very Midwest. The reason I **got** this **pop**(soda)...

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things here:

First, the verb you should be using is "to wonder" not "to wander".  To wander is to walk around.  Second, you should be using the continuing form of the verbs "to wonder" and "to hold", and you need a *determiner* before balloon to sound natural, like "this" or "the".

Put that together and you get the first, relative clause: "If you are wondering why I am holding this balloon"

Now for the second clause, first the word "so" is unnecessary.  Second, if you already specified "the balloon" in the relative clause, it sounds unnatural to repeat it.  Also, when you say "hit Mike on his head" it sounds more natural to say "hit Mike on the head".  Finally, the last "with it" is unnecessary.  All together, a native speaker might say:

**If you are wondering why I am holding this balloon, I got it in order to hit Mike on the head**

Comment: Thanks. 
I don't need to mention the words "with it"? (I mean that I hit on his head with this balloon)

Comment: @Assiduous - With this wording, you don't need to say "with it." The sentence says, "I got **it** to hit Mike on the head," so the "it" is already there.

Answer (score 1):

The first construction *sounds* more natural to me, but nothing keeps it from being as accurate as the second one.

Some notes about the sentences:

1) I guess that with "wander" you meant "wonder" - to imagine or to think about something. "Wander" means to walk aimlessly.

2) The word "so" sounds strange for me. I don't think it fits there. You could strip it off, as to make it more accurate.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I meant to wonder. :D